# Ansible - Execute task based on Linux service status

Tags: ansible

How can I write an Ansible playbook to start my nginx service only if firewalld.service is in stop state?

Note: Execution being done on a sandbox server. So no issues about firewalld in stop state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the service status, register a variable, and based on the variable result - start the service.

You can also use the service_facts module to get the service status.

Example:

```
- name: Populate service facts
  service_facts:
  
- name: start nginx if firewalld.service is stopped
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started
  when: ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service'].state == 'stopped'
```

Note: I did not tested that. Modify it accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been unsuccessfully trying to do that for a while; can you please help me with the playbook which can achieve the task?

Comment: Edited the original comment

Comment: Once service facts are gathered, you start nginx `when: services['nginx.service'].state == 'stopped'`. Adapt to your exact service name

Comment: @VishwasM.R services fact is returning `state` not `status`. And I don't really get why you are going through a loop....

Comment: @TelinovDmitri
The playbook worked when I replaced 'stopped' with 'inactive'. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As already proposed by @Telinov, you can get facts for services and start your own service accordingly:

```yaml
---
- name: Populate service facts
  service_facts:

- name: start nginx if firewalld.service is stopped
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started
  when: ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service'].state == 'stopped'
```

Meanwhile, ansible is about describing state. If you **need** firewalld stopped and nginx started, it is much easier to just say so:

```yaml
- name: Make sure firewalld is stopped
  service:
    name: firewalld
    state: stopped

- name: Make sure nginx is started
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started
```

You could be even smarter combining the above and open the firewall ports for nginx if it is running.

```yaml
---
- name: Populate service facts
  service_facts:

- name: Make sure port 80 and 443 are opened if firewall is running
  firewalld:
    port: "{{ port }}/tcp"
    state: enabled
    permanent: true
    immediate: true
  loop:
    - 80
    - 443
  loop_control:
    loop_var: port
  when: ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service'].state == 'running'  

- name: Make sure nginx is started
  service:
    name: nginx
    state: started
```

Comment: The playbook was suggested by Telinov Dmitri. I'm the one who asked the question! 
Thanks for the additional use cases.